# Cross-referencing figures in text gives wrong label

Tags: cross-referencing

I am trying to cross-ref figures in text with code like "Figure `\ref{Fig. 1.1}`". At the end of my document, I have the following:

```
\section{Figures}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.6]{figures/Miech2021.png}
    \textbf{\caption{Prevalence of nicotine vaping among US $10\textsuperscript{th}$- and $12\textsuperscript{th}$-grade students, by year in grades 10, and 12 from 2017-2020 (from Miech et al., 2021)}}
    \label{Fig. 1.1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.5]{figures/Miech2019cannabis.png}
    \textbf{\caption{Trends in 30-day cannabis use prevalence in grades 8, 10, and 12 from 2015-2019 (from Miech et al., 2019: based on Table 5-5c)}}
    \label{Fig. 1.2}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.7]{figures/Miech2019cigarettes.png}
    \textbf{\caption{Trends in 30-day prevalence in grades 8, 10, and 12 from 1975-2019 (from Miech et al., 2019: Figure 5-4q CIGARETTES)}}
    \label{Fig. 1.3}
\end{figure}
```

The in-text cross-ref reads "Figure 1.3". Any idea why when I reference Fig 1.1, the in text says "Figure 1.3"?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: don't put `\caption` inside `\textbf` (or any group, but especially not a formatting command)

Comment: That solved the referencing issue, but in "Figure 1.1:Prevalence of nicotine vaping among US10th- and12th-grade students, by year ingrades 10, and 12 from 2017-2020 (from Miech et al., 2021)", Figure 1.1 is unbolded and the rest is bolded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As David Carlisle indicated in the comments, you shouldn't include `\caption` inside `\textbf{…}` (in this case, it is likely that you get your reference to the section 1.3, and not to the figure, because `\caption` inside a group fails to define the reference for a `\label` outside of that group).

I suggest using `\bfseries` instead:

```
\section{Figures}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.6]{figures/Miech2021.png}
    \bfseries \caption{Prevalence of nicotine vaping among US $10\textsuperscript{th}$- and $12\textsuperscript{th}$-grade students, by year in grades 10, and 12 from 2017-2020 (from Miech et al., 2021)}
    \label{Fig. 1.1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.5]{figures/Miech2019cannabis.png}
    \bfseries \caption{Trends in 30-day cannabis use prevalence in grades 8, 10, and 12 from 2015-2019 (from Miech et al., 2019: based on Table 5-5c)}
    \label{Fig. 1.2}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.7]{figures/Miech2019cigarettes.png}
    \bfseries \caption{Trends in 30-day prevalence in grades 8, 10, and 12 from 1975-2019 (from Miech et al., 2019: Figure 5-4q CIGARETTES)}
    \label{Fig. 1.3}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest that you load the `caption` package with the option `font=bf` in order to bold-face the captions.

Incidentally, I can see no valid reason for processing `10\textsuperscript{th}` and `12\textsuperscript{th}` in math mode; text mode does just fine.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage[font=bf]{caption} % <-- new
\begin{document}

\section{Figures}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering

    \includegraphics[scale=.6]{figures/Miech2021.png}
    \caption{Prevalence of nicotine vaping among US 10\textsuperscript{th}- and 12\textsuperscript{th}-grade students, by year in grades 10, and 12 from 2017--2020 (from Miech et al., 2021)}
    \label{Fig:1.1}

\bigskip\bigskip

    \includegraphics[scale=.5]{figures/Miech2019cannabis.png}
    \caption{Trends in 30-day cannabis use prevalence in grades 8, 10, and 12 from 2015--2019 (from Miech et al., 2019: based on Table 5-5c)}
    \label{Fig:1.2}

\bigskip\bigskip
    \includegraphics[scale=.7]{figures/Miech2019cigarettes.png}
    \caption{Trends in 30-day prevalence in grades 8, 10, and 12 from 1975--2019 (from Miech et al., 2019: Figure 5-4q CIGARETTES)}
    \label{Fig:1.3}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```